# Changing working directory in matlab to current script dir with running blocks

Tags: matlab, block, working-directory

Is there a way to change the current working directory to current script directory with running code just inside one block of script? Script folder is not added to path.

Redefined: Is there a way to to change the current working directory to script that's currently active in editor?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the solution (was looking in wrong direction before).

```
tmp = matlab.desktop.editor.getActive;
cd(fileparts(tmp.Filename));
```

Comment: Unlike the solutions using `mfilename`, this one actually works when you're not running the command inside the file itself (or when executing a cell).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mfilename` to get the current script name, `cd(fileparts(mfilename))` should change to the correct directory.

If you frequently have to run scripts which need to be run in their script directory, you can use this function:

```
function varargout=run_in_dir(fun,varargin)
location=which(func2str(fun));
assert(exist(location,'file')~=0,'fun does not seem to be a m. file');
old_dir=pwd;
cd(fileparts(location));
try
if ~isempty(varargin)
    [varargout{1:nargout}]=fun(varargin{:});
else
    [varargout{1:nargout}]=fun();
end
catch ME
    cd(old_dir)
    rethrow(ME)
end
cd(old_dir)
end
```

To run `sin(3)` in the directory where `sin` is defined, use `run_in_dir(@sin,3)`

Comment: I think it is cd(fileparts(mfilename('fullpath')));

Comment: Or `cd(fileparts(which(mfilename)))` -- but only `cd(fileparts(mfilename))` does not work.